# Как заменить кодировки в спец символы

Tags: замена

Есть текстовый файл test.txt с кодировкой:

```
&#33; 

&#8364; 

&#10006;

&#1099;

и тд
```

Как перевести эти кодировки в соответствующие им символы: **! € ✖ ы** и тд

Пробовал вручную командой `sed -i -e 's/&#1099;/ы/g' test.txt` Всё работает, но таких символов больше тысячи. Такая работа займет больше дня.

Comment: Через `python3` это можно в несколько строк сделать: `import html; html.unescape('&#33;  &#8364;  &#10006;  &#1099;')  # '!  €  ✖  ы'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через [python3](/questions/tagged/python3) это можно в несколько строк сделать.

Алгоритм:

- Использование одной кодировка, пусть будет `utf-8`
- Открыть файл на считывание (`f_in`)
- Открыть другой файл на запись (`f_out`). Можно и в тот же файл сделать запись, но, думаю, лучше в новый, чтобы не делать потом бэкапы
- Через встроенную библиотеку `html` выполняется замена: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape

Пример:

```py
import html

with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f_in, \
        open('new_test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f_out:
    text = f_in.read()
    f_out.write(html.unescape(text))
```

**test.txt**:

```
&#33;
Hello
&#8364;
Мир
&#10006;
!
&#1099;
```

**new_test.txt**:

```
!
Hello
€
Мир
✖
!
ы
```

Comment: Вот прямо Спасибо! Это именно то, что мне нужно было!

Answer (score 0):

В `Java` есть специальная библиотека для работы с текстом:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Пример использования:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    soutUnescaped("&#33;");
    soutUnescaped("&#8364;");
    soutUnescaped("&#8364;");
    soutUnescaped("&#1099;");

    // !
    // €
    // €
    // ы
}

private static void soutUnescaped(String escapedString) {
    System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(escapedString));
}
```